# Minimizing complex exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

I have to minimize the following expression with respect to $z$:

$$\left\| e^{-j\beta z}+\|\Gamma\|e^{j\left(\theta +\beta z\right)} \right\|$$

with $ 0 \leq \|\Gamma\| \leq 1$ and $j = \sqrt{-1}$. This is known as the voltage in a transmition line with $\Gamma$ the coefficient of reflection. Hope you can help me out !

Comment: Are you sure about the exponent $j(\theta+j\beta z)$ ?

Comment: Sorry about that ! editing now !

Answer (score 2):

The sum achieves a minimum modulus when the two terms are in phase or in opposition, i.e.

$$-\beta z=\theta+k\pi.$$

When this is the case, the modulus reduces to

$$\left\|1+\|\Gamma\|e^{-\beta z}\right\|=\left\|1\pm\|\Gamma\|e^\theta\right\|.$$

Take the sign that achieves the smallest value.

---

After the fix of the formula,

$$-\beta z=\theta+\beta z+k\pi$$

and the solution is

$$\|1-\|\Gamma\|\|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

If we plot this on the complex plane we will notice that the minimum ocurres at:

$$2\beta z + \theta = \pi$$

Comment: This doesn't match the problem statement.